# Best linear spline - inequaltiy.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

For a ﬁxed set of knot points $\omega^N$, let $L$ be the operator that maps the continuous function $f$ to its linear spline interpolant $l ∈ \mathcal{L}$.

Let $l=L(f)$ prove that for every $l^* \in \mathcal{L}$: $||f-l||_\infty \le ||f-l^*||_\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's true. For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ with knot points $-1,1$. The linear interpolant is $l(x)\equiv 1$, with $\|f-l\|_\infty=1$. But $l^*\equiv 1/2$ has $\|f-l^*\|_\infty=1/2$.